# jQuery Validation Form message position

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, position, message

This is a part of my validate method:

```
...
 rules: {
           name: {
               required: true
           },
           surname: {
               required: true
           },
           tel: {
               required: true,
               digits: true
           }
      },
      errorElement: "div" ,
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {   
        error.insertAfter(element)     
    }....
```

The problem is that when validate method has to put the message on the form, it doesn't erase the previous error message if it exists. So I have for example this situation (if the validate method is run 2 times):

```
NAME:
HTML_TEXT_INPUT
ERROR1
ERROR2
```

When the second error is in `errorPlacement`, it doesn't remove the previous ERROR1.

Hoe can I fix this?

**Update**: In jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/michelejs/Ax7Bs/ it works, but at http://mongolera.dyndns.biz/projects/regioni/form2.php i have the same problem!

What could it be?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, any chance you can use [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3ddP/4/) as a base to show this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you got this to run at all, here is one issue with your implementation:

[image: container is not defined]

This is actually causing the validation script to not run at all for me on FF5 on the page you linked to.

I'm happy to provide more feedback if you can provide a working example.

**EDIT1**: I see this is working in Chrome, but you should still either define `container` or remove that line, you may see the issue disappear.

**EDIT2**: I see you are using version 1.5.2 of the validation plugin on your page, while the jsfiddle uses version 1.8. Both demos use jQuery 1.6.

There are known issues with jQuery 1.6 and any version of the validation plugin below 1.8, I suggest you upgrade to the latest version, as I don't see any apparent errors in the code you have provided, and as you see it is working fine in the fiddle. Here is the link for the current validation plugin:

- Stable: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
- Latest: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

Comment: I have removed it but the problem still exist.:(

Comment: For example you can try to insert on email folder a string like "aaa". after go on tel folder and insert letter. Repeat this 2 passage and you can see the problem

Comment: .............It works! I can not believe what a fool! EDIT2 solve the problem. Tank you Wesley you are a friend!
Thanks a lot!